# How to count the number of visible rows in html table that contains a specific word

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

so i have a csv parser and in html i want to know the the number of occurrences of a specified word in visible rows after searching for something

here is my code:

```
function no(){

     var input, filter, table, tr, td, cell, i, j;
     filter = document.getElementById("searchInput").value.toLowerCase();

    table = document.getElementById("table1");
    tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
      tr[i].style.display = "none";
      const tdArray = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td");
      for (var j = 0; j < tdArray.length; j++) {
        const cellValue = tdArray[j];
        if (cellValue && cellValue.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          tr[i].style.display = "";
          break;
        }
        //var update = $('table tr:contains(Update)').length;
  
      }
  
  
    }
      var update =  $('table tr:contains(Update)').length;

      update = "Update Operations: " + update

      document.getElementById("update").innerHTML = update;
     
      var HardDelete= $('table tr:contains(HardDelete)').length;
      HardDelete = "HardDelete Operations: " + HardDelete
      document.getElementById("HardDelete").innerHTML = HardDelete;

      var SoftDelete = $('table tr:contains(SoftDelete)').length;
      SoftDelete = "SoftDelete Operations: " + SoftDelete
      document.getElementById("SoftDelete").innerHTML = SoftDelete;

      var Create = $('table tr:contains(Create)').length;
      Create = "Create Operations: " + Create
      document.getElementById("create").innerHTML = Create;
      

    }
  </script>
```

i wrote this `var Create = $('table tr:contains(Create)').length; )`   like this `var Create = $('table tr:contains(Create) tr:visible').length;` but it wont work.

but i dont know how to write it properly can you please help?

Comment: Add the HTML to your question.